# How to use setters on extended classes of ImmutableJS Record

Tags: javascript, overriding, setter, extends, immutable.js

I want to use immutable to implement my domain-model. So I've looked and searched and found a nice commonly used pattern based on extension of Records.
The only problem I have is: I cannot get the `.set` or `.merge` function to work as it should.

Let's use the following example:

```
const SpecificRecord = Record({id: 0, someProp: ''});

export default class SpecificClass extends SpecificRecord {

  id: number;
  someProp: string;

  constructor(id, someProp) {
    super({id, someProp});
  } 

  isSomePropFancy = () : boolean => {
    return this.someProp === 'fancy';
  }
}
```

So far so good. The problem starts when trying to manipulate the record:

```
const obj: SpecificClass = new SpecificClass(1, 'not-fancy');
console.log(obj.isFancy()); //prints out false
const newObj = obj.set('someProp', 'fancy'); //returns a Record -> should be SpecificClass
console.log(newObj.someProp) //prints out 'fancy'
console.log(newObj.isFancy()); //this fails: isFancy is not a function
```

The question I have is: how can we override or whatever solution to let us update an extension of a Record, while keeping the correct class and all its methods?

Off the record: right now I use this, but I'm really really really not happy with this solution:

```
//In SpecificClass I override:
set = (key, value): SpecificClass => {
  const values = super.toObject();
  values[key] = value;
  return new SpecificClass(values);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual advice for arrow functions is "when in doubt, use it". In this case, it breaks the record factory. Simply change it to a regular function:

```
const SpecificRecord = Record({id: 0, someProp: ''});
class SpecificClass extends Immutable.Record({id: 0, someProp: ''}) {
  constructor(id, someProp) {
    super({id, someProp});
  } 

  /* bad
  isFancy = () => {
    return this.someProp === 'fancy';
  }
  */

  // good
  isFancy() {
    return this.someProp === 'fancy';
  }
}

const obj = new SpecificClass(1, 'not-fancy');
console.log('fancy:', obj.isFancy()); //prints out false
const newObj = obj.set('someProp', 'fancy'); //returns a Record -> should be SpecificClass
console.log('new obj prop:', newObj.someProp) //prints out 'fancy'
console.log('is new obj fancy?', newObj.isFancy());
```

Comment: A likely explanation on why it fails: Babel Stage 2 has [class property-transformation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) enabled, which turns `isSomePropFancy` into a static class method

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, class instance methods and Records really don't mix well.

Record methods (like `.set`) don't maintain the prototype chain, because they return a new Record, as if you had called the factory again. The problem is that `isSomePropFancy` is defined on SpecificClass.prototype, so you will lose access to it when the new Record is created.

You can either use a method override like you have for every Record method (although I don't think yours will work as you have it):

```
const SpecificRecord = Record({id: 0, someProp: ''});

export default class SpecificClass extends SpecificRecord {

  id: number;
  someProp: string;

  constructor(id, someProp) {
    super({id, someProp});
  } 

  isSomePropFancy = () : boolean => {
    return this.someProp === 'fancy';
  }

  set = (key, value): SpecificClass => {
    const values = {...this, [key]: value};
    return new SpecificClass(values.id, values.someProp);
  };

  // also need to define merge, delete, etc.
}
```

or set `isSomePropFancy` into the record as a property:

```
const SpecificRecord = Record({
    id: 0,
    someProp: '',
    isSomePropFancy: (): boolean => this.someProp === 'fancy'
});

export default class SpecificClass extends SpecificRecord {

  id: number;
  someProp: string;
  isSomePropFancy: () => boolean;

  constructor(id, someProp) {
    super({id, someProp});
  } 
}
```

---

Either way, as a side note, I highly recommend that the constructor takes an object instead of individual parameters. It makes the internal logic and usage easier and more maintainable. You wouldn't even need to define a constructor.

(e.g. `new SpecificClass({id: 1, someProp: 'not-fancy'})` instead of `new SpecificClass(1, 'not-fancy')`)

We use TS and Records, and I convinced my team that it is much cleaner to not wrap Record types in classes at all, and just type the factories as-is.